# Как получить html код dom элемента

Tags: javascript, dom

Необходимо получить **html** код **дочернего** dom элемента, зная id родителя и **childNodes[index]** элемента. Буду признателен за примеры. **.innerHtml** к сожалению, возвращает текст, а не html.

```html
<div id='parent'>
    <div id='children1'></div>
    <div id='??'>
        <div id='n1'></div>
        ..........
        <div id='n99'></div>
    <div id='children3'></div>
<div>
```

```
indexDOM = 2;
document.getElementById("parent").childNodes[indexDOM];
```

Comment: Не понятен вопрос... HTML-код - это и есть строка) Может имеется в виду `outerHTML` ?

Comment: Точно, спасибо, то что нужно. Вывод: нужно больше спать по ночам прежде чем вопросы задавать xD